# Infragistics Dll reference Wrong Dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, version, infragistics

I have a C# Application written in WPF in Visual Studio 2015

The application uses several WPF controls from Infragistics, cheif among which is the XAMDATACHART and associated CHARTINFOSTRIPS

SETUP

I added a reference to the following dlls, using the normal visual studio procedure:

InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Editors.XamCalendar.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Core.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v15.2
InfragisticsWPF4.v15.2
All of these dlls have a version of 15.2.20152.2038

I also added a reference to IGDataChart (version 15.2.20152.84)

The main infragistics dlls were taken from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Infragistics\2015.2\WPF\CLR4.0\Bin folder and the IGDataChart was taken from the C:\Users\Public\Documents\Infragistics\2015.2\WPF\Samples\CLR4.0\Binaries folder

Problem

On my development PC (on which I installed Infragistics) everything runs absolutely fine and works perfectly.

On a test production PC (on which Infragistics has not been installed) I get an error.

The error is "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v15.2, Version=15.2.20152.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

The line of code at which this error occurs is "var chartStrips = new ChartInfoStripsBehavior();"

I have checked the GAC on the production machine which has no references at all to any Infragistics dll. The only dlls supplied with the application are the ones specified earlier.

I have checked and re-checked the versions of the referenced dlls, and the versions of the output dlls, and they all seem to be the most recent versions of the dlls.

I have run the Infragistics Version Update Utility, which states that all components are up to date.

I have opened the project.cs file and manually checked the versions in there

I cannot find any reference anywhere in the application or debugging info that suggests that the dll "InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v15.2" should be version 15.2.20152.1000 and not 15.2.20152.2038

This problem has only just reared its head in the last two days after two months of successful tests with the application.

I have asked this question on the IG forums but would like to know if anyone here has any thoughts.

Comment: Why do you add/get a dll from the Samples folder? If you have updated your versione from 1000 to 2038 is possible that the Samples folder has not been updated

Comment: where would the updated IGDataChart.dll be then?